# R - installing FFTW3 package on Windows machine

Tags: r, windows, cartogram

I am trying to build a **cartogram** with R following the [algorithm of Gastner & Newman](http://www.pnas.org/content/101/20/7499.abstract) on diffusion-based methods for producing density-equalizing maps

I have [found a recipe](http://vietletruc.com/tag/cartogram/) on how to do it with help of the `Getcartr` and `Rcartogram` packages; however, this requires installation of the Fast Fourier Transform libraries `FFTW3` and `fftw`.

I installed `fftw` easily from CRAN, but I have a problem with `FFTW3`, which I could only find as an archived file [here](http://www.fftw.org/download.html).

I get the following error message when trying to install the package from a .zip file:

> `install.packages(choose.files(), type="source", repos=NULL)`
>
> Installing package into ‘H:/R.shiny.tutorial/libraries’  (as `lib` is
>   unspecified)
>
> Warning in `read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package",
>   "Type"))` :    cannot open compressed file 'fftw-3.3.4/DESCRIPTION',
>   probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>
> Error in `read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package",
>   "Type"))` :    cannot open the connection
>
> Warning in `install.packages` :    running command
>   '"Q:/RSTUD301.001/R-32~1.0/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "H:\R.shiny.tutorial\libraries" "F:/cartogram/fftw-3.3.4.zip"' had
>   status 1  Warning in `install.packages` :    installation of package
>   ‘F:/cartogram/fftw-3.3.4.zip’ had non-zero exit status

I found some tips on installing `FFTW3` on Mac and Linux, but I work on a **Windows** machine.

I found similar problems online but their solutions do not work for me.

Here is my `session.info()`:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) 
Platform: **i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)**
Running under: **Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1**

locale: 
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252     

attached base packages: 
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached): 
[1] tools_3.2.0
```

Can you help?

Comment: FFTW3 isn't an R package. You need it on your system for fftw to work but it's not an R package.

Comment: I run into this problem a while back. Never found a solution, but I was able to use VirtualBox to use a Linux distribution and then install this package. You might have to consider downloading VirtualBox or buying an AWS instance with Linux. Hopefully someone figures this out for Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the replies. @Mike, any chance reaching you on priv? My e-mail in the profile.

Comment: sure thing. I will send it now